# Mongo Db collection size using conditions

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo db for my dashboard project. Now i have to study the limitations of my project. My schema for this is is as follows :

```js
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5388796faff25d43f4b07c62"),
    "users" : 4611679,
    "shouts" : 12821459,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-01-07T00:00:00Z"),
    "user" : "52a82b20701054a10a000f12",
    "events" : 0,
    "profile" : 0,
    "appName" : "mukund"
 }
```

the field 'appName' can take many values. I am using the mongo db command:
         db.collectionn.stats()
to see the memory size of the collection. Now the problem is that i want to know the size of the collections which are having appName as 'mukund', it means i want to filter the appName then apply the command on the filtered result but i am unable to do it using the mongo db command 'db.collection.stats()'. Can anyone suggest me some other ways. Thank you......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to calculate the total size:

```
var totalSize = 0;
db.test.find({appName: 'mukund'}).forEach(function(obj) {
    var size = Object.bsonsize(obj); 
    totalSize += size;
})
print(totalSize); //prints size in bytes
```